# Eclipse Hover Color

Tags: eclipse

So I just went through the process of making my Eclipse dark mode. I'm already down 3 hours, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of this large box that pops out when you hover over certain functions. Please help. I want the table dark with the text and background light.

[image]

Comment: Over what kind of functions? In which editor? With the included Dark theme?

Comment: With the standard built-in Dark theme everything should appear dark. But it is up to each plug-in to make sure it uses the correct ways of doing things. What exactly is that view?